# rails NoMethodError: undefined method `hotel'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I'm new to Rails. Similar code worked when I compledted Hartl's tutorial. The difference is that there was a Micropost model, and now I've created Hotel model for my own app.

And Model specs do not pass. I think that problem is about assotiations, but who knows... Spent the whole day yesterday and couldn't make them pass. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here is error and my code:

```
Failures:

  1) Hotel 
     Failure/Error: before { @hotel = user.hotel.build(title: "Saffron") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `hotel' for #<User:0xb3c2d2c>
     # ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Hotel 
     Failure/Error: before { @hotel = user.hotel.build(title: "Saffron") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `hotel' for #<User:0xb5b1200>
     # ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Hotel 
     Failure/Error: before { @hotel = user.hotel.build(title: "Saffron") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `hotel' for #<User:0xb7364b8>
     # ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Hotel 
     Failure/Error: before { @hotel = user.hotel.build(title: "Saffron") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `hotel' for #<User:0xb42a9cc>
     # ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Hotel when user_id is not present 
     Failure/Error: before { @hotel = user.hotel.build(title: "Saffron") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `hotel' for #<User:0xbc7ba40>
     # ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Hotel user 
     Failure/Error: before { @hotel = user.hotel.build(title: "Saffron") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `hotel' for #<User:0xbefae4c>
     # ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.11 seconds
33 examples, 6 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:10 # Hotel 
rspec ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:12 # Hotel 
rspec ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:11 # Hotel 
rspec ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:15 # Hotel 
rspec ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:19 # Hotel when user_id is not present 
rspec ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:13 # Hotel user
```

hotel.rb

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hotels
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  before_create :create_remember_token

  has_secure_password  
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  .....
```

hotel_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Hotel do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { @hotel = user.hotel.build(title: "Saffron") }

  subject { @hotel }

  it { should respond_to(:title) }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:user) }
  its(:user) { should eq user }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when user_id is not present" do
    before { @hotel.user_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

Migration for Hotels table

```
class CreateHotels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :hotels do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :hotels, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

Comment: Try `before { @hotel = user.hotels.build(title: "Saffron") }`.Note `hotels` not `hotel`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Such a simple mistake. It must be because I started Hotel model from the very beginning today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to rails

You should read the [guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

This code means a a user has many hotels (with a **s**):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hotels
```

So if you are looking for all the hotels of a `user` you can use the code `user.hotels`, which is a collection (of many hotels), so you can use all ruby and rails collections methods. For example:

```
# This will output to your console the name of each hotels linked to that user
user.hotels.each do |hotel|
  puts hotel.name
end
```

Now if you are looking for the first hotel of the collection you can use `users.hotels.first`

And a lot more things are possible. Read the guide I linked at the beginning of my message, also you can have a look at http://railscasts.com that have a lot of good material available for free (and some for a fee, but for the basic learning, the free episodes are very good)